# How to call a function in Windows 8 app?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I created a function like this:

```
text: function () { 
    document.getElementById("id").innerText = "Hello";
}
```

I tried to call this function from another function like this and it doesn't work:

```
anotherFunction: function () {
    this.text();
}
```

The error I get:

Unhandled exception at line 89, column 21 in ms-appx://b9f1ea0e-9eeb-41e4-a788-92c282715e21/pages/game/game.js

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'text45'

Note: text45 is my function name.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: For one thing, 'text' is a reserved word (by Windows), so you shouldn't use it as a function name. Reference: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp

Comment: Have you tried replacing `GetElementById` with `getElementById` (lowercase g), as you should be getting the error `document.GetElementById is not a function`

Comment: That's not the problem, I changed it and it doesn't work yet. (For the first response)

Comment: In my code I wrote getElementById() (with lower case g). It fails when I call the function, not in the function itselft.

Comment: Find out a way to get the error message(s) and edit your question to provide it. Some great tools like `Deveolper Toolbar` for firefox will help visualizing those errors.

Comment: I added it to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
There is no way (From what I know) to call a function that is not in the function itself. When I write the function like a regular function in the function itself it worked.
Example for what I found:

```
anotherFunction: function () {
    function textchange() {
        document.getElementById("id").innerText = "Hello";
    }
    text();
}
```